# Why is this average rule true?

Tags: statistics, average

Let $\overline{a}$ represent the average of the quantity $a$.

I have seen this law being used many times:
 $\overline{ab}=\overline{a}\times\overline{b}$

Can anyone share a proof on why this is true?

Comment: $\overline{XY}=\overline{X}\,\overline{Y}$ is true for independent variables $X,Y$ but not in general.

Comment: Which type of average are you referring to?  There are many including geometric mean, arithmetic mean and others.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the **average** of $ab$? Are you looking at a set of data? If so, do you have the same number of values for $a$ as for $b$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a$ be the average of $a_i, i = 1 \to n$ and $b$ be the average of $b_j, j = 1 \to m$. Then, $na =  \sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ and $mb = \sum_{j=1}^m b_j$.

Simply multiplying both sides, $abmn = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m a_ib_j$. Taking the $mn$ to the other side,
$$\boxed{
ab = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m a_ib_j}{mn}}
$$

The right hand side, however, is the sum of all products $a_ib_j$ divided by the number of such elements $a_ib_j$. Therefore, the RHS is infact the average of the $a_ib_j$, while the left hand side is the product of the individual averages, as desired.

Read the other answer for more details on the above phenomena.

Comment: I think that taking $\bar{ab}$ as the average of the terms $a_ib_j$ is an unusual use of terminology.

Comment: Yes, but that is what I think was meant.

Answer (score 1):

Let's represent the values of the quantities you mention by $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ and $b_1,\ldots,b_n$ so that
$$
\overline a=\frac{a_1+\cdots+a_n}{n},\qquad \overline b=\frac{b_1+\cdots+b_n}{n},
$$
and similarly
$$
\overline{ab}=\frac{a_1b_1+\cdots+a_nb_n}{n}.
$$
Your question is asking whether (or under which conditions)
$$
\frac{a_1b_1+\cdots+a_nb_n}{n}=\frac{a_1+\cdots+a_n}{n}\times\frac{b_1+\cdots+b_n}{n},
$$
or equivalently
$$
n(a_1b_1+\cdots+a_nb_n)=(a_1+\cdots+a_n)(b_1+\cdots+b_n).
$$
This is just an equation involving the $a_i,b_i$ values and it could be either true or false depending on their values. On the right side there are $n^2$ terms, one for each possible $(i,j)$ combination $a_ib_j$. The left side consists of the $n$ diagonal terms $a_ib_i$, but each is multiplied by $n$ to make up for the discrepancy.

One thing to notice is that if $a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_n$, then the equation is true. (And likewise for $b_1=\cdots=b_n$.) But there are many more solutions, which is expected since there are $2n$ unknowns and only $1$ equation, so there are $2n-1$ degrees of freedom.

Okay, so just looking at the equation itself doesn't tell us too much - we need to put it in context by bringing in probability (this was already suggested in the comments before I wrote this answer). The average is a special case of a more general quantity - the [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value). Expected values are defined for certain random variables. In the case when the values $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ are distinct and the random variable takes each of these values with equal probability $1/n$, then the expected value is the average. In symbols, we can call the random variable $A$, satisfying
$$
\mathbb P(A=a_i)=\frac{1}{n},\qquad \textrm{for every $i=1,\ldots,n$},
$$
and likewise for $B$. Then the statement that "average equals expectation" translates into
$$
\overline a=\mathbb E[A],\qquad \overline b=\mathbb E[B],
$$
where $\mathbb E$ is the shorthand for "taking expectation of a random variable".

So your question boils down to asking when
$$
\mathbb E[AB]=\mathbb E[A]\mathbb E[B].
$$
This equation holds if and only if $A$ and $B$ are [uncorrelated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncorrelatedness_(probability_theory)). In fact, this equation is so important that it is the basis for the concept of [covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance), defined as
$$
\textrm{covariance}(A,B)=\mathbb E[AB]-\mathbb E[A]\mathbb E[B],
$$
i.e. the left side minus the right side of the previous equation. Saying that $A$ and $B$ are uncorrelated is the same thing as saying that their covariance is zero.

The most common way for random variables to be uncorrelated is if they are [independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)), which is a more advanced concept. (But not too much more...)